# How to check a string in a list of string?

Tags: python, find

i just want to compare a string with a list of string

if the pattern of letters matching to the list, the  i want a simple true as output

see my example below:

```
a = ["jackpot","guru","otto","name"]
    
    
s = "tttguruugfhghd"


    if s contain in a:
        print("hit")
    else:
        print("no hit")
```

output should be:

```
hit (in this case)
```

i think there is a easy solution, but i didn't find anything yet

ok, now this is working, but now i have a new question:

```
a = ["jackpot","guru","otto","name"]    
s = "guruu"

if s in a:
    print("hit")
else:
    print("no hit")
```

if i run this code i get a no hit but i want a hit even if "s" the string is not 100% matching but i contains the pattern

Answer (score 1):

We can traverse the list and check if entries are `in` the `s` string; once found, we break the loop:

```
for seq in a:
    if seq in s:
        print("hit")
        break
else:
    print("no hit")
```

where we use `for` with `else` to detect *any* hit or not (`else` is kind of "no-break" here). But `any` is better:

```
if any(seq in s for seq in a):
    print("hit")
else:
    print("no hit")
```

which reads "if any of the `seq` in the list `a` is contained in `s`, then print "hit"; else "no hit"".

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `string.find` instead of the `in` keyword? `any(seq in s for seq in a)` seems easier to me

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Oh, not at all.. Thanks, edited. It was complicating for no reason...

Comment: thank you very much this solves my problem!!!!!

Comment: @pythonbeginner glad to be of help! If you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/791774) one of the answers here that solves your problem to signal others that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
if s in a:
```

instead of

```
if s contain in a:
```

Also, you have unnecessary indentation.

EDIT, answering question.
Then you need to iterate..

```
a = ["jackpot","guru","otto","name"]

s = "jackpottt"

contains = False

for entry in a:
    if entry in s:
        contains = True
        print("hit")

if not contains:
    print("no hit")
```

Comment: thanks for this answer i am not at my final goala = ["jackpot","guru","otto","name"]    
s = "guruu"

if s in a:
    print("hit")
else:
    print("no hit")  in this case i want to see a hit, but how?

Comment: See my edit, pretty simple example based on what you had.

Answer (score 0):

I would check each element for the solution.

```
if len([ a_elem for a_elem in a if a_elem in s]) > 0:
    print("hit")
```

Above we have a list comprehension that filters the elements of a on the basis of whether or not they exist in s. If the length of the filtered list isn't empty, there is at least one hit.